# Sampling an element from a list in R

Tags: r, list, vector, sample, sampling

I have a list called `MyList` that looks like this:

```
[[1]]
[1] 5

[[2]]
integer(0)

[[3]]
[1]  5 16

[[4]]
[1] 9

[[5]]
integer(0)
```

I want to sample one of the numbers 5,5,16,9 along with which list element it has come from. E.g. if the first 5 is picked out I would like the sample result to be c(1,5) but if the second 5 is chosen I want the result to be c(3,5). I also don't want to include empty values `integer(0)` in the sampling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to bring this list in a more manageable data structure (like matrix or a dataframe) dropping the empty values.

```
mat <- unname(do.call(rbind, Map(function(x, y) 
               if(length(y)) cbind(x, y), seq_along(MyList), MyList)))
mat
#      [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    5
#[2,]    3    5
#[3,]    3   16
#[4,]    4    9
```

then select any one row from the matrix.

```
mat[sample(nrow(mat), 1),]
```

**data**

```
MyList <- list(5, integer(0), c(5, 16), 9, integer(0))
```